# How do you instantiate a java.lang.reflect.Method?

Tags: java, reflection

My method accepts a `Method` object as a parameter. Therefore, I need to create a mock up instance of a `java.lang.reflect.Method`. It turns out the class is `final` and has no public constructor. Okay. So... Is there some factory I need to use or what...? The `java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess` class is package scoped and it appears to be the sort of factory I'm looking for (except for the fact I can't use it). What's the deal here...?

Yeah, I could always get an instance of some `Class` and pick a random `Method`, but I suppose there's a much more sensible way...?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Yeah, I could always get an instance of some Class and pick a random Method, but I suppose there's a much more sensible way...?

No, that *is* the sensible way. Nothing else makes sense. What would it even mean to have a method which isn't part of a class? What would happen when you invoked it?

If this is for testing, I suggest you create a class with an appropriate method in it specifically for this purpose.

Comment: Well, if there really is no way to get an instance of a `Method`, then I suppose I could mock up a dummy class with some test methods in it, but that wasn't exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: @carlspring: What exactly *did* you have in mind? What would `Method.getDeclaringClass` return in whatever you had in mind, for example? A class which *didn't* declare that method? How would that be *better* than using a real method?

Comment: I think there are use cases where this could actually be useful; for instance when bridging between code using a MethodExpression and an API expecting a Method. In that case you would need to create a Method instance dynamically based on the type info of the MethodExpression. Looking at the source for Method in the Oracle JDK this would be rather straightforward if it wasn't for the final modifier. Synthesizing a (static) method dynamically (e.g. using the compiler API) just for this purpose is perhaps an option, but a bit over the top...

Answer (score 5):

Try to use reflection.

```
Constructor c = Method.class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.class, String.class, Class[].class, Class.class, Class[].class, int.class, int.class, String.class, byte[].class, byte[].class, byte[].class);
c.setAccessible(true);
c.newInstance(....); // send correct arguments
```

This should work.

Comment: Brilliant, I should have thought of this!

Comment: After testing this, it actually doesn't work. It throws a NoSuchMethodError, which is unfortunately correct.

Answer (score 2):

Method is always related to a class (or instance), so what's the use of getting a method not from its class?

Comment: As mentioned in my (now updated) question, my method accepts a `Method` as a parameter. I would like to pass in a few mocked `Method`-s for the sake of testing. Obviously, a `Method` is always associated with a `Class`, you are clearly right.

Comment: Can't you create a mocked class just for that?

Comment: Of course -- I can always create a dummy class for testing, but this wasn't exactly what I had in mind and it is somewhat ugly and not the intuitive thing.